# do infinite family of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have a common point by knowing that any three of them have common point?

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-geometry

Suppose we have given an infinite family of lines; say $\mathfrak{F}$, in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that any three of the lines in $\mathfrak{F}$ have a common point. How can we prove that all lines in $\mathfrak{F}$ have a common point.

(here we should note that using Helly theorem is not applicable, because first of all we are working on an infinite set of convex sets and second that no of them are closed and bounded!)

Comment: Isn't this effectively trivial?  You can show that any two pairs of lines $\langle\ell_a, \ell_b\rangle$ and $\langle\ell_c, \ell_d\rangle$ must share the same intersection point: apply the hypothesis to $(\ell_a, \ell_b, \ell_c)$ to show that $\ell_b$ and $\ell_c$ intersect in the same point as $\ell_a$ and $\ell_b$ and then apply them to $(\ell_b, \ell_c, \ell_d)$ to show that $\ell_c$ and $\ell_d$ intersect in that same point.

Comment: Or even more simply: pick two lines $\ell_a, \ell_b$ to start with and then for any other line $\ell_*$ use the hypotheses applied to $(\ell_a, \ell_b, \ell_*)$ to show that it passes through the intersection point of $\ell_a, \ell_b$, and thus all lines pass through that intersection point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that any *two* distinct lines in the family have *at most* one point in common. Take any three distinct lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$ from the family, and let $v_0$ be their common point. Take any $l$ in the family distinct from these, and consider $\{l_1,l_2,l\}.$

**Added**: This result is actually true in all $\Bbb R^n$ (vacuously when $n=1,$ since there is no infinite family of lines, in the first place).

Comment: Bingo. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Pick $L_1,L_2,L_3$. These have a common point $x_0$. In particular,
$L_1, L_2$ have $x_0$ as a common point.

Now pick any other line $L$ in the collection. Since $L_1,L_2,L$ have a common point, it must be $x_0$.

Hence all the lines pass through $x_0$.